# isotope.js - how to solve rendering wrong spaces in fluid layouts

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope, grid-layout, fluid-layout

As for the subject, I've got problems with isotope and fluid layouts. I don't think it's really an isotope problem itself. Probably some render issue browsers have when objects are treated/positioned like isotope does.

Please see attachment. Sometimes it happens. Not always. Often, by resizing slightly the window (or sometimes just reloading) all the spaces just disappear and the layout gets right.

I think it's a quite common problem. If I take a look to thumbs dimensions in firebug, well, they're all just right. So I guess it has something to do with the browser rendering capabilities.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I don't know about isotope, but your question seems very vague, and your problem is certainly not reproducible (for people looking to answer your question). It's usually a good idea to provide any code that is relevant to your problem, and to give specific information about the problem. What you have provided is an overview of what the problem is, without providing details that help the community solve your issue.

Comment: No. I think it's a really well known problem for people using isotope on a responsive layout, and in this specific case any code would be irrilevant, since if a solution has ever been found, it's in some isotope tweak or in a very special manner of doing a responsive grid, despite of whatever I'm currently doing. If you want to be fully able to judge, you must first know the piece of software we're writing of here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit more, I think isotope positions objects in a way that's going to fool the browsers rendering engines when elements are sized with percentage values. Using the percentPosition not only doesn't solve the trick, but cause filtering animations to be far more sluggish.

Modifications to isotope need too much work for me now, but I've just found another script that seems to be specifically coded with responsiveness in mind (thus, demonstrating how common the problem is). I didn't try it yet, but I took a look to the code and I think it's really well done:

https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/

So, for now this is the answer. Hope it helps.

A brief note: currently, mixitup doesn't support mansory layout out of the box. This was not a problem for me though, since my layout is a regular square grid.

Comment: Many people do know what your speaking of and have used isotope code extensively and your comments are misplaced, condescending  and incorrect. You should always provide code with your question as a courtesy and as part of the spirit of this community.  Don't judge people trying to help you. We actually do know more than you assume.  And your answer is to use another plugin that you haven't even tried yet or even know if it solves your problem? This is not an answer.

Comment: I'm preatty sure that any coder having the same problem will be happy with my answer, as far as he doesn't need to use exclusively isotope for some reason (ex. mansory layout, platform dependencies, etc..). I tried mixitup, it works (and far better), but I was quite sure: again, the problem here is how isotope positions elements (forced absolute positioning). Mixitup doesn't use absolute positioning (translations instead), and that solves the issue.

Comment: Interesting interpretation of down voting on your question.

Comment: I've upvoted for the helpful content in the answer, but I would ask that long paragraphs of perceived voting injustice are not added to posts. Most people reading did not vote on the question or the answer, and just want to see the problem or the solution `:-)`.